# Nested Navigators navigation and Custom TabBar issue

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, navigation, react-navigation

[What I'm Trying to Achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm9sM.png)

I'm Trying to achieve a Tab Navigator which has Two tabs on each side which don't redirect to a different tab but instead open their respective Side Drawer as shown in the Picture.

Now, I want to use these drawers to navigate to various pages since there are a lot of pages and i don't want them all in my Tab bar.
However, I want the Tab bar to be shown in all the pages for easy navigation.

Additionally, I'm not able to make the Circular drawers a part of the TabBar hence i'm having to Render it conditionally on every page based on a global Zustand State, like so,

```js
import { useDrawerStore } from '@/store/drawerStore';
const Home = () => {
  const { isOpen, setIsOpen } = useDrawerStore()
  return (
    <BackgroundImage>
        <Landing/>
        {isOpen && <CustomDrawer isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} />}
    </BackgroundImage>
  )
}

export default Home
```

This doesn't seeem like a good approach to me and i would much rather have the Drawers be a part of the TabBar.

My folder structure looks like this:-
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZKjZ.png)

The _layout file in app/ directory has a Stack Navigator and the _layout file in app/private/ directory has the Tab navigator. I have used Expo Stack in the parent layout but React Navigation bottom tabs in child Layout file.

I am unable to achieve the navigation  since `navigation.navigate("home/notifications")` is not working unless i put the screen in the Tab Navigator and
`navigation.dispatch(StackActions.push("/home/notifications"))` is also not working for some reason.

The dispatch code gives the Error :-

```
The action 'PUSH' with payload {"name":"/home/notifications"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named '/home/notifications'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.
```

I also tried to Render the Custom Drawer with my Tab Navigator but the Drawer is rendering inside the small space of the TabBar and not the Entire Screen.

This is the code for what i tried:-

```js
return (
<>
{isOpen && <CustomDrawer isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} />}
 <Tab.Navigator>
   //Tab.Screens Here
 </Tab.Navigator>
</>
)
```